# Comment traduire « skimmability » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais

J'ai un petit souci pour traduire « skimmability » vers le français. Je veux pouvoir dire « la survolabilité d'un **texte** » de manière correcte, entre autres en phrase nominale pour un titre. « Survolabilité » n'existe pas selon larousse.fr et « potentiel de survol » ou autre « capacité de survol » ne semble pas très bon. Je suis preneur de toute suggestion astucieuse !

Comment: Simple curiosité : est-ce conçu comme une qualité objective d'un texte, un aspect positif ? Je ne trouve pas de définition en ligne, hormis quelques marchands.

Comment: Ce que je veux dire, c'est que si un jour j'écrivais un livre et qu'on me disait constamment qu'il est très *survolable*... j'aurais quand même du mal à le prendre pour un compliment ;-)

Comment: Dans mon cas c'est un aspect positif oui, je travaille sur des ressources éducatives et le fait de pouvoir les exploiter à la vitesse que l'on décide la plus adaptée évite de devoir perdre du temps à étudier des choses que l'on maîtrise déjà.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Skim* se traduit normalement en français dans ce sens par *lire en diagonale*. Mais *lisibilité en diagonale* ne marche pas vraiment, passer du verbe au nom perd le côté idiomatique de l'expression. Cela amène donc à *capacité à être lu en diagonale*, ou moins précis mais un peu moins lourd *capacité de lecture en diagonale*. Suivant le contexte, dans un titre, *lecture en diagonale* peut suffire.

Comment: Lecture en diagonale ne fait pas vraiment référence à une technique et est plus fort que lecture rapide à mon sens.

Comment: @Amphiteóth « Lecture en diagonale » signifie explicitement qu'on ne lit pas tout. « Lecture rapide » n'a pas ce sens.

Answer (score 6):

[This](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/parcourable) **II.B.1** suggests that “*parcourable*” would be best.

I had thought that “feuilletable” would do.  See the verb form [*feuilleter*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/feuilleter). It seems to have the sense of “leafing through”.

Comment: I agree that "feuilletable" has a physical action component that cannot be ignored.

Comment: @Circeus  Useful to have that confirmed, thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure french by itself would produce such a hideous word. A periphrasis with a complete sentence reconstruction would be required, in my opinion.

Comment: @KOthetypo  which?

Comment: @Micromégas “Parcourabilité”.